# video framework for ios

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

Is there any alternative frameworks for AVFoundation to play video file? 
I have a problem with AVFoundation which is described in following topic.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074753/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-disappears-after-video-has-finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different video players in the iOS frameworks: MPMoviePlayerController and AVPlayer.

If MPMoviePlayerController is not working for what you want, try AVPlayer. It has less features, but it's easy to use.

Here is the guide:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html